# Catching and handling global exceptions in Android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

We are trying to prevent the app to restart on exception log the error and kill the app gracefully.
We use the `AndroidEnvironment.UnhandledExceptionRaiser += HandleAndroidException; in the mainLauncher / activity to catch unhandled exceptions.`

Problems are:

1. In the HandleAndroidException method, we wish to display a notification to the user letting know the application will close.
   The activity object is not available so we are unable to show a **HUD / dialog**.
2. After showing the dialog we wish to kill the app and prevent it to restart in a unusable state. ( have tested `this.FinishAffinity(); ,Finish();         System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();` etc.)
   The app still restarts.
3. In the same method we try to track the error in Visual Studio App Center
   (Crashes.TrackError(e.Exception);) The exception is not logged in the appcenter.
   (Writing the error to a local logfile works fine.)

Comment: You can't show a dialog, but you can start a Activity to show the dialog.